# CSS styling issues for a close button

Tags: html, css

if you go [here](https://theplate.ro/meniu/) and add "Piept de pui la gratar" to your cart, there will be a popup.
I tried modifying the close button's CSS because I want it fully yellow (including hover and non-hover states), but it just doesn't seem to work.

I've tried setting the color and background-color. The background color seems to work, but I don't want to change it. Setting the color to yellow just doesn't seem to make it. Any help is appreciated.

CSS Code:-

```
a#thp-close-id {
    color:yellow; 
    background-color: yellow; 
}
```

Also tried:-

```
.thp-close {
     color: yellow;
     background-color: yellow; 
 }
```

I also tried flagging the `color` property as `!important`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Kindly, share the minimum code that you wrote.

Comment: ```a#thp-close-id {
    color:yellow;
    background-color: yellow;
}```

Comment: also tried
```.thp-close {
color: yellow;
background-color: yellow;
}```

Comment: moreover, I tried flagging them as ```!important```. Even though it's not good practise, I want it to work first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't work, it's because you are trying to apply those styles to the wrong 'element', as the close button uses its pseudo classes, see screen:

[image]

So in order to achieve what you need, try writing this css instead:

```
.thp-close:before, 
.thp-close:after {
    background-color: #f4c001;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! Indeed, I didn't know that the close button uses its pseudo classes because I wasn't the one who made it, so thank you very much for your answer

Comment: Not a problem at all :) If I can give you a little suggestion, try always looking the styles from chrome / firefox dev tools, as they really help you out understanding where all styles are applied. If you want to know more about it, have a look at this awesome guide: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/css - I'm sure you will find it really useful, mainly to understand how things are built in websites you didn't develop!

Comment: Thank you! I'll look it up there. As a matter of fact, I was using inspect element from both Chrome and Firefox